# Custom module use lib

Tags: perl, directory

I have a standalone Perl module that I want to use, however I cannot get 'set lib' to work. What am I doing wrong?

I am working off the terminal in Mac OS and the module is located in a folder on my desktop `/Users/John/Desktop/HT/Conlang`.

```
#! perl -w

package HT::Conlang::S17;

use strict;
use vars qw($VERSION @EXPORT_OK);
use base 'Exporter';
use lib '/Users/John/Desktop/HT/Conlang';
use HT::Conlang::S17;
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working. when i try to run the module in the terminal nothing happens.

Comment: OK .. what is (not) wrong here?  (1) What is the exact error you get? (2) Why do you have `use HT::Conlang::S17;` _inside_ that very package? (3) The directory looks "suspiciously" close to the location the module is in -- is this module in a directory just above the one you are trying to set?

Answer (score 2):

Problem #1. It doesn't make sense to use `use lib` inside a module. It belongs in scripts. And even then, if it's an absolute path (as opposed to a path relative to `$FindBin::RealBin`), it's far better to set env var `PERL5LIB` than to use `use lib`.

Problem #2. If your module uses package `HT::Conlang::S17`, it should be loaded using `use HT::Conlang::S17;`, which means Perl will search for `HT/Conlang/S17.pm`, so the entry to add to `@INC` should be `/Users/John/Desktop`.

Problem #3. `/Users/John/Desktop` contains more than just Perl modules. You should have a directory dedicates to being a Perl library directory.

---

Solution, part 1. Move `/Users/John/Desktop/HT` to `/Users/John/perl5/lib/HT`.

Solution, part 2. Have your login process add `/Users/John/perl5/lib` to the env var `PERL5LIB`.

Comment: Solution 1: I copy pasted the folder from my desktop to the perl5 lib
Solution 2: I have no idea how to do this, what exactly should I enter to do this?

Comment: What OS are you using? OS/X? I don't know.

Comment: ...but Google says [Setting environment variables in OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: I've gone ahead and done all of that. The program still won't work.

Comment: Provide the output of the following: `printf "PERL5LIB: %s" "$PERL5LIB" ; ls -ld /Users /Users/John /Users/John/perl5 /Users/John/perl5/lib /Users/John/perl5/lib/HT /Users/John/perl5/lib/HT/Conlang /Users/John/perl5/lib/HT/Conlang/S17.pm ; perl -e'use HT::Conlang::S17;'`